# How can I enable Animator Duration Scale from my code?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am having trouble with this issue, I need to enable that from code, because of some users disabling this option, how can I do this? so far I've tried this but with no luck.

**option 1:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
     Settings.Global.getFloat(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
            1f);

} else {
   Settings.System.getFloat(
            getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
            1f);
}
```

**option 2:**

```
durationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(getApplication().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE, 1);
   if (durationScale != 1) {
            try {
                ValueAnimator.class.getMethod("setDurationScale", float.class).invoke(null, 1f);
                durationScale = 1f;
                Log.v("NOSEQUEPEX","HOLA");
            } catch (Throwable t) {
               Log.v("VALIOSHIT",String.valueOf(t));
            }
        }
```

Hope someone could help me thank you.

Comment: Why? If the user has disabled animations on their device, they don't want to have animations.

Comment: if the user has that disabled, then the app crashes and the don't know is because of that, even I struggled a lot before I found out it was because of that

Comment: You should ask about that then.